# Spring Batch CharacterEscapeHandler property ignored

Tags: spring, escaping, spring-batch, jaxb2

It looks like Spring Batch StaxEventItemWriter when used with JAXB2Marshaller does not recognize the Marshaller Properties that are set. Has anyone had experience using CharacterEscapeHandler in SpringBatch?

I need JAXB to ignore escaping special characters like '<' and '>' to '& lt;' and '& gt;' (Please ignore spaces) and I did override 'initJaxbMarshaller' of my JAXB2Marshaller as follows, however it doesn't seem to recognize..

```
@Override
    protected void initJaxbMarshaller(Marshaller marshaller)throws JAXBException{
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),  new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void escape(char[] buf, int start, int length,
                    boolean isAttVal, Writer out)
                    throws IOException {
                for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++) {
                    char ch = buf[i];
                    log.debug(ch);
                    out.write(ch);
                }
                //log.debug("Just flushing char --> "+ch.toString());
                //writer.write(ch, start, length);
            }
        });
    }
```

Edit: Adding more information..

Desired XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<LOAD FORMAT="XMLFormat" OVERRIDE="true">
  <USER ID="someId">
    <NAME>userName</NAME>
    <COMPANY><![CDATA[companyName]]></COMPANY>
  </USER>
  .....
<LOAD>
```

Java Object Mapping

```
@XmlRootElement(name="USER")
@XmlType (propOrder={"name","comapny"})
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CdataAdapter.class)
    private String company;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

CdataAdapter class for handling CDATA

```
public class CdataAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String>{

    @Override
        public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return "<![CDATA[" + v + "]]>";
        }

        @Override
        public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return v;
        }
    }
```

JAXB2Marshaller Spring config

```
<bean id="userXMLMarshaller" class="org.test.model.xml.marshallers.CustomJAXB2XMLMarshaller">
   <property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
        <value>org.test.xml.User</value>
    </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Actual XML output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<LOAD FORMAT="XMLFormat" OVERRIDE="true">
  <USER ID="someId">
    <NAME>userName</NAME>
    <COMPANY>&lt;![CDATA[companyName]]&gt;</COMPANY>
  </USER>
  .....
<LOAD>
```

Also, It looks there is a bug with Spring batch already that doesn't intend the output XML properly and there is fix for it; Link - https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2113

Do ya'll think it's the same case with the CharacterEscapeHandler as well ? Any suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: may your post a sample of your file and jaxb mapped objects?

Comment: Luca, made edits to my post as requested..

Comment: sorry, can't help after some tries. Maybe Minella (or someone others) can give advices/a solution about this problem

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to try Luca.

Comment: Harish , I face the same issue happening for me. Did you solve this ?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci, Could you help me with a marshalling problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031311/java-lang-illegalstateexception-marshaller-must-support-the-class-of-the-marsha